# Linq to Sql query, datediff +-3 days

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm working with a flights page. Right now I got some flights in my database and I want to display them.
With this query I'm displaying all flights on the selected date (asp:calendar control):

```
var destinationFlights = 
    (from a in db.Flights
     where a.DepartureAirportId == depId && a.DestinationAirportId == destId && a.DepartureDate == depDate
     join Airports a1 in db.Airports on a.Airports.AirportName equals a1.AirportName
     join Airports a2 in db.Airports on a.Airports1.AirportName equals a2.AirportName
     select a).ToList();
```

The thing I want to achieve is if I for example choose date (2014-10-10) from the calendar form, I want the query to search in the table and show me all flights in the interval of +-3 days from selected date. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try searching? Did you find `DateTime.AddDays()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need is to work out the start and end dates, then use comparisons in your `where` clause:

```
var earliest = depDate.AddDays(-3);
var latest = depDate.AddDays(4); // Exclusive

var destinationFlights = ... 
    where ... && a.DepartureDate >= earliest && a.DepartureDate < latest
    ...;
```

Comment: This is the way to go, because (in my experience at least) LINQ providers usually don't map `DateTime` methods to the respective SQL functions without custom extensions.